# How to load translations from another bundle

Tags: php, symfony, twig, translation

I have two bundles: `AppBundle` and `AnotherBundle`.

I have to translate a string in `AppBundle`:

```
{% trans from 'anotherbundle' %}anotherbundle.string{% endtrans %}
```

The problem is that when I extract the strings to translate with JMSTranslationBundle, the file `anotherbundle.en.xlf` is created inside the `AppBundle/Resources/translations` directory while I want it to be created in `AnotherBundle/Resources/translations` directory.

To extract the translations I use this command:

```
bin/console translation:extract en --config=app
```

and the configuration I use is this:

```
jms_translation:
    configs:
        app:
            dirs: ["%kernel.root_dir%", "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/"]
            output_dir: "%kernel.root_dir%/../src/AppBundle/Resources/translations"
            ignored_domains: [routes, FOSUserBundle]
            excluded_names: ["*TestCase.php", "*Test.php"]
            excluded_dirs: [cache, data, logs, web]
```

How can I make JMSTranslationBundle extract the translating string into `AnotherBundle` directory?

Answer (score 0):

I always leave the options blank and the translations are available in every single bundle I use. I only have to refer to the domain.